# Add binaries to Job / e.g. keystore.jks

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Some of my test are running against binary files. E.g. keystore.jks.
This is a test-keystore but I don't want this file in my GH-Repo. What's the best way to add such files to a Jenkins-Job?

I thought there must be a plugin for this problem but I couldn't find one.

**Update:**
"Copy to slave"-plugin works fine for "normal" Jobs but how can I copy files from userContent to the slave if I define the Job as pipeline?

Comment: Hmm - I think I found a solution: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/User+Content - what do you think?

Comment: Think I have the solution: https://plugins.jenkins.io/copy-to-slave This plugin allows to copy a set of files, from a location somewhere on the master node, to jobs' workspaces. It also allows to copy files back from the workspaces of jobs located on a slave node to their workspaces on the master one.

Answer (score 0):

I could not found a solution with Jenkins - so I handed it over to Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'

// Username + Token gibt es unter
//      http://localhost:10080/me/configure
//
// Diese Vars sind definiert:
//     JENKINS_HOST
//     JENKINS_PORT
//     JENKINS_USER
//     JENKINS_TOKEN
//
// Weitere Infos: https://www.michel-kraemer.com/recipes-for-gradle-download/
task downloadCertIfItDoesNotExist(
        type: Download ) {

    def resourceFolder = new File("${project.projectDir}/src/test/resources")
    def etcFolder = new File( "${resourceFolder}/etc" )
    def zip = new File("${resourceFolder}/etc.zip")

    def jenkinsHost = System.getenv('JENKINS_HOST')
    def jenkinsPort = System.getenv('JENKINS_PORT')
    def ciHost = System.getenv('CI_HOSTNAME')

    // Sample:
    //  http://mobiad.int.mikemitterer.at:10080/userContent/certs/kdeneon.int.mikemitterer.at/etc/*zip*/etc.zip
    def url = "http://${jenkinsHost}:${jenkinsPort}/userContent/certs/${ciHost}/etc/*zip*/etc.zip"

    // https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html
     onlyIf {
        !etcFolder.exists() || project.hasProperty('forceETCUpdate')
    }

    src url
    dest zip

    username System.getenv('JENKINS_USER')
    password System.getenv('JENKINS_TOKEN')

    quiet false
}

task unzipETCZip(
        type: Copy,
        dependsOn: downloadCertIfItDoesNotExist) {

    def resourceFolder = new File("${project.projectDir}/src/test/resources")
    def etcFolder = new File( "${resourceFolder}/etc" )
    def zip = new File("${resourceFolder}/etc.zip")

    onlyIf {
        zip.exists()
    }

    from zipTree(downloadCertIfItDoesNotExist.dest)
    into resourceFolder
}

task prepareCertsFolder (
        group: "Jenkins",
        type : Delete,
        dependsOn: [ unzipETCZip ] ) {

    def resourceFolder = new File("${project.projectDir}/src/test/resources")
    def zip = new File("${resourceFolder}/etc.zip" )

    onlyIf {
        zip.exists()
    }
    delete zip
}
```

This solution works quite nice for me.

This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
    ...
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh './gradlew test -PforceETCUpdate'
        }
    }
    ...
```

In my build.gradle I connect the test to `prepareCertsFolder`

```
test.dependsOn "prepareCertsFolder"
```

Hope this helps someone...